# How do I add a paddingBottom to a drawer layout in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am working on an android project that uses a drawer layout. The drawer layout contains many items and is therefore scrollable. The problem is, I need the last item to have a padding bottom such that there will be some spacing after scrolling to the last item.

[image]

From the screenshot above, how can I add some padding between the last item 'Log out' and the end of the screen.

I have tried adding padding bottom to the drawerlayout but its still not working

```
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_120sdp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
```

I have also tried enclosing navigation view in a scrollview but it is also not working

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_120sdp">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</ScrollView>
```

This is my last element in the drawer layout

```
<item
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_190sdp"
        android:title="@string/action">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_rate_us"
                android:title="@string/rate_us" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_120sdp"
                android:title="@string/log_out" />

        </menu>
    </item>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add one dummy items to the end of your menu resource file.

```
 <item
    android:title=""
    android:enabled="false" >
</item>
```

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect your suggested changes. Still doesn't work